# flake8 not showing fatal erros in vscode

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-code, flake8

Vscode is not showing fatal erros in vscode. It is only highlighting warnings in the code. Example:

I have vscode running flake8 from a virtualenv with python 2.7. The settings is as following:

```
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
```

I'm comparing the results from vscode "problems" window with the results of running flake8 directly from the command line.

```py
def foo(bar):
    o += 1

    print(bar)
```

When I run flake8 from the command line on the code above, I get all linting errors and warnings,

```
> flake8 python/mock.py 
python/mock.py:4:5: F821 undefined name 'o'
python/mock.py:4:5: F841 local variable 'o' is assigned to but never used
python/mock.py:5:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
```

while when I lint this code in vscode, I only getting the warnings.

```
blank line contains whitespace flake8(W293) [5,1]
```

Am I missing something in the configuration? Is there a way to check how flake8 is being called by vscode?

Comment: It turns out that the problem was the version of flake8. Using the latest version was not working, so I explicitly set to use flake8==3.5 and then it started working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

The default configuration works for me (also with Python2.7 on virtualenv).

[image: flake8]

Check that:

- The path to the `flake8` executable is explicitly specified in *settings.json*

  ```
  # From terminal/console, install flake8 into your virtual environment
  $ pipenv install --dev flake8
  $ which flake8
  /absolute/path/to/virtualenvs/test-v9MbxBL-/bin/flake8

  # Set in settings.json
  "python.linting.flake8Path": "/absolute/path/to/virtualenvs/test-v9MbxBL-/bin/flake8",
  ```
- The severity for Fatal and Error categories are set to "Error":

  ```
  "python.linting.flake8CategorySeverity.F": "Error",
  "python.linting.flake8CategorySeverity.E": "Error",
  ```
- There are no ignored errors:

  ```
  "python.linting.flake8Args": [
      "--ignore=F821"
  ]
  ```
- There are no overriding flake8 settings [from external sources](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_flake8)

  > Flake8 user options are read from the `C:\Users\<username>\.flake8`
  > (Windows) or `~/.config/flake8` (macOS/Linux) file.
  >
  > At the project level, options are read from the `[flake8]` section of a
  > `tox.ini`, `setup.cfg`, or `.flake8` file.

Comment: manually specifying the path to flake8 in settings.json worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Usually yeah it will. But if it doesn't work for you, then you can try specifying absolute path to flake8 and enable it explicitly like so :

```
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,  
"python.linting.flake8Path": "path/to/flake8",
```

you can even specify path to your conda environment :

```
"python.condaPath": "path/to/condaenv/",
```